# how write action to form with wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I add new table in wordpress database and I create form to insert data in this table but the data don't insert into the table and appear to me "Oops! That page can’t be found." .

 all code in the same page it's name "cv-employersignup.php"

```
<?php
function addnewemployer(){
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $country = $_POST["country"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];
    $confpass = $_POST["confpass"];
    $cellphone = $_POST["cellphone"];
    $website = $_POST["website"];

    if($name !="" && $country  !="" && $email !="" && $pass !="" && $confpass !="" && $cellphone !="" && $website !="" && $pass == $confpass){
        $newwmployer= "INSERT INTO employer (company_name,country,email,password,phone,website) VALUES ('".$name."' , '".$country."' , '".$email."' , '".$pass."' , '".$cellphone."' , '".$website."')";

        if(mysql_query($newwmployer)){
            echo "<script> alert('<p> مرحبا بك في موقع سى ڨى <br> لقد سجلت بيناتك بنجاح <br>
            من فضلك قم بتاكيد بريدك الالكترونى </p>'); </script>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<script> alert('نعتذر هناك خطا من فضلك حاول التسجيل مره اخرى');</script>" ;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<script> alert('من فضلك املئ جميع الخانات'); </script>";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['addemployer']))
    {
        addnewemployer();
    }
}
?>

<div class="col-lg-12 signup">
    <div class="col-lg-6 employer">
        <form action="#" method="_POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder=" اسم الشركة " name="name" class="form-control input-lg">
            <input type="text" placeholder=" بلد الشركة  " name="country" class="form-control input-lg">
            <input type="email" placeholder=" البريد الالكتروني " name="email" class="form-control input-lg">
            <input type="text" placeholder="كلمة المرور " name="pass" class="form-control input-lg">
            <input type="text" placeholder=" تأكيد كلمة المرور" name="confpass" class="form-control input-lg">
            <input type="text" placeholder=" رقم الجوال " name="cellphone" class="form-control input-lg">
            <input type="url" placeholder=" الموقع الخاص بالشركة " name="website" class="form-control input-lg">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block" name="addemployer" onclick="addnewemployer()"> تسجيل </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what is the error

Comment: I don't know if this was just a bad paste on  your part, but this `</div` is missing a `>` for it.

Comment: you failed to respond. Either you left the question or waiting for a magic potion. Good luck, I've left the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line where you run the **addnewemployer()** is inside of the function **addnewemployer()** - you need to take it out and add it to after the function itself.

```
function addnewemployer(){ 
    // your function as above
    ... 
}
if(isset($_POST['addemployer']))
{
    // notice how it actually calling it now
    addnewemployer();
}
```

You should also be using WordPress's native **[wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)** to achieve this. Note: you will need to call the global variable **$post** at the top of the **addnewemployer** function.

The Form "action" can also be left blank.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

This section of your code:

```
if(isset($_POST['addemployer']))
{
    addnewemployer();
}
```

Is responsible for checking if data is posted from a form to this file or not. if so, then call the `addnewemployer()` function.

But surprisingly you have place this block of code inside your function, thus this part of the code is never running and your `addnewemployer()` function is never being called.

What you have to do is to extract this block of code from your function. So your code should look something like this:

```
function addnewemployer(){
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $country = $_POST["country"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];
    $confpass = $_POST["confpass"];
    $cellphone = $_POST["cellphone"];
    $website = $_POST["website"];

    if($name !="" && $country  !="" && $email !="" && $pass !="" && $confpass !="" && $cellphone !="" && $website !="" && $pass == $confpass){
        $newwmployer= "INSERT INTO employer (company_name,country,email,password,phone,website) VALUES ('".$name."' , '".$country."' , '".$email."' , '".$pass."' , '".$cellphone."' , '".$website."')";

        if(mysql_query($newwmployer)){
            echo "<script> alert('<p> مرحبا بك في موقع سى ڨى <br> لقد سجلت بيناتك بنجاح <br>
            من فضلك قم بتاكيد بريدك الالكترونى </p>'); </script>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<script> alert('نعتذر هناك خطا من فضلك حاول التسجيل مره اخرى');</script>" ;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<script> alert('من فضلك املئ جميع الخانات'); </script>";
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['addemployer'])){
    addnewemployer();
}
```

Another issue with your code is that you have selected `wordpress` tag and also mentioned you have added this table in `wordpress` but you not using any of the wordpress features!

But the other issue with your code is using of `mysql` which is deprecated. You strongly suggested to use `mysqli` or `pdo` and then use `parameter binding` and `prepared statement` to prevent [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)